# what's difference between yolov4 and yolov7 in terms of inferencing?

Tags: yolov4, yolov7

I'm a beginner to yolo.One thing is confusing to me is the difference between versions of yolo when  using them.Is the only difference is the .cfg and .weights file I use?Do they use the same algorithm?What's the relation between yolo and their backbones?

i use code from https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet to demo,I tried yolov4-tiny.weights and yolov7-tiny.weights and it both worked?Does that mean the only difference is .cfg and .weights?